# Chrome only shows Library lines in call stack when debuggin AJAX

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have set "XHR breakpoints" to break on "Any XHR" to find , which line triggers AJAX request, but when I check the call stack - all lines are Angular.js library lines. That does not make sense, because this way I can't find which line in my code triggered the request. What should I do?

**More info:**

If that is important, the AJAX response is error, because it requests a non-existing URL.
Also when I blackbox Angular - the breakpoint does not trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular doesn't make the Ajax request immediately. Instead it queues it until the digest has finished.

You can find the code that's causing the request by intercepting the `$http.get` method, or whatever you're using to make requests.

```
debugCall($http, "get"); // put this somewhere where it's only called once

function debugCall(object, methodName){
    var originalMethod = object[methodName];
    object[methodName] = function(){
         debugger;
         originalMethod.apply(this, arguments)
    }
}
```

You could also look at the Angular call stack and try to get hints there. For example, in [this demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reYBpq) the first function in the call stack is called `eventHandler`.

If you go to that call frame and run `event.target.outerHTML` in the console you get `<button ng-click="doXhr()">Do XHR 2</button>`. That gives you a good idea of where to look for the request.

Comment: Nice insight on how Angular works. Concerniong the intercepting the $http method, the problem is that I can't find it, and that is why I have started to looking for it using the debugger. Of course I could go through the code, just wanted to make it quicker using the debugger.

Comment: @naneri Not sure I understand what prevents you from intercepting it. You only have to overwrite the `$http.get` function once, anywhere in your app. Once that's done it will pause regardless of where `$http.get` is used.